# Hub spacer behind 105 cassette

Tags: shimano, wheels, cassette, hub

While removing Shimano 105 cassette, I noticed a spacer sitting on the hub between the largest sprocket and the place where spokes attach to the hub (not sure how is it called).

I checked the 105 exploded diagram and there is no spacer behind the largest sprocket so I was wondering, what is it for? Is it just a spacer the wheel manufacturer put there?

Edit: Sorry for not including this earlier: the cassette is indeed 11-speed (11-34) and it's a road bike.

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer, I'm pretty sure this is fine because the manufacturer was mixing Shimano components to get 34t which usually isn't available in a full 105 build, it is compatible according to their chart. If you ever swap the cassette and go for a <34t road cassette, the spacer probably needs to go out. I have 11-speed 105 on a 11-speed hub and there is no spacer on my bike.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are used when the freehub body and cassette size are not matching, there are various combinations depending on the scenario

- 10-Speed cassette on 11-Speed freehub body requires both 1.85mm (FW8991) and 1.0mm (FW4671) spacer
- 9-Speed cassette on 11-Speed freehub body only requires 1.85mm (FW8991) spacer
- 34t cassettes on 11-speed *road* groupsets generally require a 1.85mm spacer because these are built using MTB specifications and may be used on both road and MTB setups (the former requiring an additional spacer)

**Updated based on the OPs update**

As the OP has stated in an update, he is running 105 with a 34t cassette (which can often be seen in compact builds because it offers 1:1 gearing in your lowest sprocket for climbing). If CS-HG700-11/CS-HG800-11 are used on a road hub, the additional spacer is required, also stated on Shimano's [product page](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-11-speed/CS-HG800-11.html)

Comment: Note that 11-34 11-speed road cassettes are in fact sold with the spacer (example: https://www.bike-components.de/en/Shimano/CS-HG700-11-11-speed-Cassette-p62072/). The strange part for me is that there is to my knowledge no 11-speed MTB derailleur that can handle such cassette, so it's where considering max compatibility just increases complexity.

Comment: @Renaud I think we just need to know what the OP is running to understand the reasoning behind. Maybe just a pre-5600 (9-speed) bike with a modern replacement wheel, who knows...

Comment: @Renaud Based on the OPs update and Shimano's compatibility chart, the OP has a 34t cassette which has a different spline type than the road-only ones (for example max. 32t for a 105 R7000). It is "HG Spline" L versus M and I suspect, you need the spacer in such setups - the 105 medium-cage RD can deal with max. 34t

Comment: which is exactly what my answer says, without the Shimano-terminology ;)

Comment: This answer is written as though 11-speed 11-34 is somehow not "road" or somehow out of place on 11-speed 105, which is not true. It's there because it's always there when any 11-34 cassette is used on an 11-speed road fhb.

Comment: @NathanKnutson You're right, it is a usual thing, I've seen that on many entry-level 105 builds with beginner/climb-friendly 1:1 gearing. Reworded the answer so that it doesn't sound like an oddball any more. I don't quite get what that has to do with "hub overhang", though ... or is it just Shimano's choice so that it can be used in "a variety of bikes", so both road and MTB?

Comment: @DoNuT 11-speed cassettes with a 34t or greater large cog take up the same amount of space on the freehub splines as any 8/9/10 cassette, because 34 and larger cogs overhang the mounting shoulder/hub flange area. So even on an 11-speed road bike with an 11-speed freehub body, the 1.85mm spacer must be used. Same with XDR and bigger cassettes etc. That's why 11 and 12 speed MTB HG hubs still have the same FHBs as before.

Comment: @NathanKnutson It just go me confused because of "34 and larger overhang...". As I understand it, it has nothing to down with the cassette sizing but only Shimano's product decision to make them work on both road and MTB, with the historically different FHB designs (while road only 11-speed ends at 32t). Since you can't install negative spacers, it only works that way... that being said, 12-speed now has 34t options that fit without spacers (but only road).

Comment: @DoNuT I don't claim to understand all the design factors, but it's something along the lines of if you were to play the same trick with too small of a largest cog, it could interfere with the hub flange.

Answer (score 6):

If have an 11-speed groupset, and the largest sprocket is equal or larger than 34T, the cassette is in fact built using MTB specifications (MTB Hyperglide freehub bodies have kept the "historical" HG freehub body, that is used on road bikes up to 10 speeds: larger sprockets can have overhang above the hub).

So if you want to use such cassette on the longer 11-speed road freehub body, you need to add a 1.85mm spacer.